Definition of free profinite product of infinitely many groups
If we have profinite groups $G_1,...,G_n$ we can define its free profinite product in the natural way. But this natural definition (similar to the abstract case but in the category of profinite groups) seems not be good if we have infinitely many factors. In the book $``$Profinite graphs and groups$"$ by Ribes ([1]) and paper $``$A Kurosh subgroup theorem for free pro-$C$ products of pro-$C$ groups$"$ by Gildenhuys and Ribes ([2]) they provide different definitions.
The natural definition would be: if $\{G_i : i \in I\}$ is a nonempty set of pro-$C$ groups, the free pro-$C$ product of the groups $G_i$ is a pro-$C$ group $G$ with a family of continuous homomorphisms $\iota_i: G_i \to G$ satisfying the following universal property: given a family of continuous homomorphisms $\varphi_i: G_i \to H$ into a pro-$C$ group $H$, there is a unique continuous homomorphism $\varphi: G \to H$ making $\iota_i\varphi = \varphi_i$.
Perhaps we could include in the previous definition the $1$-convergent condition on the homomorphisms to make it agree with free profinite groups. But this is a quite different from the definitions on [1] and [2], which seems to be the definitions used currently.
Someone know how to explain why it is like that?

My understanding is that the definition of profinite free product requires some convergence to 1 property. This is how it is defined in appendix D of the second edition of the Ribes and Zalesski book

@BenjaminSteinberg I agree (this need to agree with the definition of free profinite group as a particular case). My question is because Ribes, in his book, defines it using sheaves (which Neukirch call bundles I think). Perhaps this is the same thing after all, but in principle it seems quite different and unnatural to me.

If I recall the sheaf thing is more general.  It essentially allows you to put a topology on the index set. In some sense it is analogous to a free profinite group on a space that way.

If the index space of the sheaf is a one point compactification of a set, then I think you get the free product converging to 1 situation.

I think of the sheaf as a profinite groupoid where all the arrows are isotropy and then the free product is the universal profinite group admitting a CTS functor from that groupoid.

Of course without the convergence condition this is a valid definition. However, it might happen that this "naive" free product fails to exist. For a family $(G_i)$ of profinite groups, maybe it exists if and only if for every finite group $F$, the set of $i$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}(G_i,F)\neq{1}$ is finite?

@BenjaminSteinberg that makes sense. I wrote a sketch of this idea to convince myself.

@YCor The $1$-convergent condition is also essential to prove the expected theorems I think. But I had not thought about the possible non existence before. It is a good point!

(And actually when the condition of my last comment is satisfied, it should coincide with the "right" free product.)

@YCor What is "right" in this context?

@Lucas Isn't it clear? I mean, the condition in Benjamin Steinberg's first comment, as opposed to the "naive" one.

@YCor oh, I see.
